# Python / Selenium - access not interactive element

Tags: python, selenium

What I need:

- Select one of the options from the drop-down list
- Only BUTTON element is visible (SELECT element is not visible)

This is html code:

```
<td data-bind="css: { 'cell-error': applicantNames.hasError }, attr: { title: applicantNames.message }" title="">
    <select data-bind="options: $parent.applicants, multivalue: applicantNames" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
        <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
        <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 236px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>Please select...</span></button>
</td>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

The problem is that I would like to select one of these options by using Selenium, but because the SELECT element is not interactable/not visible ... not sure what to do...

If you will choose an option from the drop-down the BUTTON element will be updated like this

```
<button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-active" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 236px;">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>ABC, XYZ</span>
</button>
```

Even if I will update the BUTTON section manually, it will still not update the element visually..... so I'm a bit stuck to find a way how to interact with these elements by using Selenium...

P.S. I'm looking for ANY headless methods, e.g. Selenium / JavaScript execution through selenium and e.t.c...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the problem is that **"This is not built using Select - option tag"**, so one can not directly make use of `Select class from Selenium support package`.

Instead you can try to click on that menu using Selenium `.click()`
in your case something like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Please select')]").click()
```

and then store all the visible option in a list of web elements using `find_elements` and then iterate the list :

```
for option in list_of_options:
    if option.text == "your desired option"
       option.click()
```

Comment: I just found the problem, this list of options actually appeared inside the frame ..... a strange way of coding, but anyway..... so I found a way to go into this page, get visible elements and find the correct option. P.S. not sure if I need to close/delete this question

Comment: Probably you'd need to switch over to iframe.

Comment: Your answer is good :) but the key will be that the actual option list is located in a different place  (not where you believe they should be)

Comment: @OksanaOk : Generally we get `NoSuchElementException` in case of iframe.  Since it was not mentioned I did not think that it could be in an iframe. Well good luck !